# I keep getting offers for what sounds like illegal scams

Tags: scams

The *"scammers"* are telling me that:

1. I have an ATM card with 30 million dollars on it in an airport I've never been and  all I need to do is go down there and get it.
2. I pretend to be of familial relation to a soldier in Afghanistan, I send 3000 dollars in keeping fees to a family holding thing (an agency that keeps family heirlooms/money/items in storage until a family member comes of age and can get it) and they deliver 30 million dollars to my house in actual cash.
3. Federal Reserve people saying that they are going to compensate 30 million dollars in cash for recent scam victims and I am on that list.

All of these *"scams"* are asking for my "full name, address, phone number, and that I call/email/visit them".
Are these really scams? 
The reason why i'm wondering is because usually scams ask for money (in the second "scam" I would be paying an actual business and not just some random guy) and none of them are sending checks, they are all sending either cash, or an ATM cards.

Comment: Plot twist, in #2 you're the scammer: "I pretend to be of familial relation to a soldier in Afghanistan...."

Comment: The odds of 30 million dollars *legitimately* falling into someone's lap out of nowhere is... probably less than 1 in 30 million.  You are right to discount these offers.

Comment: I truly don't understand how people get dragged into these. Can you please explain what part of these seem legitimate to you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are scammy scams by a scammer.

Comment: The scammiest of scams that the scamming scammers scammingly scam the scammed with.

Answer (score 1):

I would NOT do anything. Actually, I wonder what was in the scammer's mind when he thought someone would be tricked by that?

Comment: You might be surprised.  Peruse the other questions on this site marked "scams" and see what kind of lines people have been hooked by.